# faster way to sort two models by location in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have two unrelated models. they need to be merged and sorted by distance and paginated.
I forgot that near can't be used for arrays, so I add sort to the combined model. I used near on the models first to get the Distance (the models doesn't have distance columns). but the response time is 1,5 seconds. any improvement?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I use Geocoder Gem. the "near" and "distance" is from that

```
      lat = current_user.latitude || -6.177
      lng = current_user.longitude || 106.8403

      directories = (Doctor.near([lat,lng],10_000))+(Hospital.near([lat,lng],10_000)) 

      directories = directories.sort_by{|a| a.distance}



      directories = Kaminari.paginate_array(directories).page(params[:page])
```

Comment: I guess you could restructure your app, pull out a location model that has a polymorphic association to `Doctor` or `Hospital` and stores the address, lat and longitude.  Then you can query the distance via geocoder rather than pulling them in separately and sorting in ruby.

Comment: plz, add code and detailed description for the near method. Generally improving such thing is only pissible by using a geospatial index on the database records and perform the respective query to sort the records by the database

Comment: seems that you are using geocoder. It does not use a geospatial query for other databases then mongo. But you have to add index in any case, it's descirbed in geocoder README. And you have to follow the advice of the first comment to sort both tables on db level